# How to have build.rs built and run in release mode?

Tags: rust, build-script

I have a `build.rs` that generates tables. They are expensive to calculate and I would like to run `build.rs` in release mode. However, it seems it always runs in debug mode regardless of build profile selected.

[This issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/2424) discusses this specifically, and is closed, but I'm unable to extract the tidbit that allows me to run `build.rs` in release mode regardless of the build profile I'm using. How do I do this?

Comment: I'm not sure this will work, but you can have the code in a separate crate and build.rs call that, and compile this code with opt-level=3 in debug build (https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/profiles.html#overrides).

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Oh! build-override is it, I think. Thank you. Please submit as answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 1):

You can set [`build-override`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/profiles.html#build-dependencies)'s `opt-level` to `3`. Beware that this will also optimize proc macros and build dependencies.